# Interrupt setTimeout with clearTimeout

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a custom gallery that flips through background images (using toggleClass). The gallery function loops fine.

I am trying to add the ability to go backwards (and then later forwards) by clicking .leftArrow. I can't seem to get clearTimeout to actually stop my timeouts however, and I have a feeling I'm making a rookie mistake somewhere but I can't seem to figure it out.

The problem area I think is under the interrupt on click comment.

**HTML**

```
<!-- Gallery Images -->
<div id="heroes" class="heroThree">
    <div class="heroOne hero visible"></div>   
    <div class="heroTwo hero hide"></div> 
    <div class="heroThree hero hide"></div> 
</div> 

<!-- Arrows -->
<div class="leftArrow"><i class="fa fa-arrow-left"></i></div>
```

**jQuery**

```
//GALLERY ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
var gallCheck = 1;
var check = true;

function gallery() { 

if (check == true){ 
    if (gallCheck == 0) {  
        var idOne = setTimeout(function() {
            gallCheck++;
            gallery();
            },7000);
        $('.heroOne, .heroThree').toggleClass('hide').toggleClass('visible');//toggle background
        $('.selectorThree, .selectorOne').toggleClass('fa-circle').toggleClass('fa-circle-o'); //toggle Circles
        idOne;

    }
    else if (gallCheck == 1) {
        var idTwo =  setTimeout(function() {
            gallCheck++;
            gallery();
            },7000);   
        $('.heroOne, .heroTwo').toggleClass('hide').toggleClass('visible');
        $('.selectorTwo, .selectorOne').toggleClass('fa-circle').toggleClass('fa-circle-o');
        idTwo;

    }
    else if (gallCheck == 2) {
        var idThree = setTimeout(function() {
            gallCheck = 0;
            gallery();
            },7000);
        $('.heroTwo, .heroThree').toggleClass('hide').toggleClass('visible');
        $('.selectorThree, .selectorTwo').toggleClass('fa-circle').toggleClass('fa-circle-o');
        idThree;
    } 
}

}


//INTERRUPT ON CLICK ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


$(".leftArrow").on( "click" , function() {
    var check = false;
    if (gallCheck == 0) { 
        clearTimeout(idOne);
        gallCheck =2;
        var check = true;
        gallery();
    }
    else if (gallCheck == 1){
        clearTimeout(idTwo);
        gallCheck--;
        var check = true;
        gallery();
    }
    else if (gallCheck == 2){
        clearTimeout(idThree);
        gallCheck--;
        var check = true;
        gallery();
    }
});
```

**EDIT**

Code is fixed. update:

```
//GALLERY ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
var gallCheck = 1;
var check = true;
var idOne = setTimeout(function() {
            gallCheck++;
            gallery();
            },7000);
var idTwo =  setTimeout(function() {
            gallCheck++;
            gallery();
            },7000); 
var idThree = setTimeout(function() {
            gallCheck = 0;
            gallery();
            },7000);

function gallery() { 

if (check === true){ 
    if (gallCheck === 0) {  

        $('.heroOne, .heroThree').toggleClass('hide').toggleClass('visible');//toggle background
        $('.selectorThree, .selectorOne').toggleClass('fa-circle').toggleClass('fa-circle-o'); //toggle Circles
        idOne;

    }
    else if (gallCheck == 1) {

        $('.heroOne, .heroTwo').toggleClass('hide').toggleClass('visible');
        $('.selectorTwo, .selectorOne').toggleClass('fa-circle').toggleClass('fa-circle-o');
        idTwo;

    }
    else if (gallCheck == 2) {

        $('.heroTwo, .heroThree').toggleClass('hide').toggleClass('visible');
        $('.selectorThree, .selectorTwo').toggleClass('fa-circle').toggleClass('fa-circle-o');
        idThree;
    } 
}

}


//INTERRUPT ON CLICK ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


$(".leftArrow").on( "click" , function() {
    check = false;
    if (gallCheck === 0) { 
        clearTimeout(idOne);
        gallCheck =2;
        check = true;
        gallery();
    }
    else if (gallCheck === 1){
        clearTimeout(idTwo);
        gallCheck--;
        check = true;
        gallery();
    }
    else if (gallCheck === 2){
        clearTimeout(idThree);
        gallCheck--;
        check = true;
        gallery();
    }
});
```

Comment: i think its your timeout variable scope problem. your click function is not getting the value of the timeout variable, try to make the variable global

Comment: Now it is interrupting but it is not running the function gallery(); again. That's definitely a start though. Thanks!!

Comment: I dont think that has anything to do with timeout, debug your code, and post if any error is there.

Comment: why have you used the check variable in the click function? The check is not doing anything.

Comment: Figured it out. I was using var check = false; instead of just check = false;

I was defining new variables instead of changing values. Thanks a ton for your help once again!

Comment: exactly what I just asked you :)

Comment: Yup and it worked out great! Thanks for the lookover.

Comment: It seems unintentional that the gallery is static to begin with, and then when it starts to rotate, it toggles visibility in a funny way: http://jsfiddle.net/a71ku5jw/1/ -- however, since my CSS here is ultra-simplified, maybe it's working out properly with your production styles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to declare idOne idTwo and idThree at global scope otherwise they are not accessible in the clearing methods below

Comment: That is making the clearTimeout work now, but it is not running gallery(); again after that. Definitely a step forward though, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Your `idOne idTwo idThree` variables are local variables, they are not accessible to the function with the clearTimeouts.

Comment: That is making the clearTimeout work now, but it is not running gallery(); again after that. Definitely a step forward though, thanks!